# submit button is not work properly in python 3 . how to solve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import  tkinter.ttk

class window1( Frame ):
    def __init__( self ):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack()
        self.master.title("MANAGEMENT")

        self.button1 = Button( self, text = "ENTRY", width = 25,command = self.GUI)                        
        self.button1.grid( row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W+E+N+S )

        self.button2 = Button( self, text = "SHOW BILL", width = 25 )
        self.button2.grid( row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W+E+N+S )

        self.button3 = Button( self, text = "MEMBERS", width = 25)                      
        self.button3.grid( row = 2, column =1 , columnspan = 2, sticky = W+E+N+S )

    def GUI(self):
        self.GUI= GUI()


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.buttonDic = {
        '1':0,
        '2':0,
        '3':0,
        '4':0
        }

        for key in self.buttonDic:
            self.buttonDic[key] = tk.IntVar()
            aCheckButton = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=key,
                                            variable=self.buttonDic[key])
            aCheckButton.grid(sticky='w')

        submitButton = tk.Button(self, text="Submit",
                                        command=self.query_checkbuttons)
        submitButton.grid()

    def query_checkbuttons(self):
        for key, value in self.buttonDic.items():
            state = value.get()
            if state != 0:
                print(key)
                self.buttonDic[key].set(0)



def main(): 
    window1().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: value is't print when i press submit button. @fedterzi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two Tk() instance running in your code. The first one is hidden inside the `window1` call when you init the frame with no parent and the second in the `GUI` class. Since you don't specify the parent of the `IntVar`, they are associated with the first created window, so not the right one.

I modified your code in the following ways:

- I made the `Window1` class inherit from `Tk` since you are using it as your main window
- I made your `GUI` class inherit from `Toplevel` to avoid having two running `Tk` instances in the program
- I specified the `IntVar` parent, so that there is no ambiguity

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window1(tk.Tk):  # inherit from Tk instead of Frame
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("MANAGEMENT")

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="ENTRY", width=25,command = self.GUI)                        
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="wesn" )

        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text="SHOW BILL", width=25 )
        self.button2.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="wesn")

        self.button3 = tk.Button(self, text="MEMBERS", width=25)                      
        self.button3.grid(row=2, column=1 , columnspan=2, sticky="wesn")

    def GUI(self):
        self.GUI= GUI(self)


class GUI(tk.Toplevel):  # inherit from Toplevel instead of Tk
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.buttonDic = {
        '1':0,
        '2':0,
        '3':0,
        '4':0
        }

        for key in self.buttonDic:
            self.buttonDic[key] = tk.IntVar(self)  # specified the parent of IntVar explicitly
            aCheckButton = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=key,
                                          variable=self.buttonDic[key])
            aCheckButton.grid(sticky='w')

        submitButton = tk.Button(self, text="Submit",
                                 command=self.query_checkbuttons)
        submitButton.grid()

    def query_checkbuttons(self):
        for key, value in self.buttonDic.items():
            state = value.get()
            if state != 0:
                print(key)
                self.buttonDic[key].set(0)


def main(): 
    Window1().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```